# Moving an ArrayController/View to a Component in Ember 1.13

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently in the process of updating my Ember App to use 1.13 and am having an issue translating a particular `Ember.View` and its associated `Ember.ArrayController` into an `Ember.Component`, as per the [Deprecation Guide](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view).

After repurposing some code, I now have the following:

**app/templates/page.hbs**

```
{{example-component content=posts}} // "posts" being an array of objects
```

**app/templates/components/post-list.hbs**

```
{{#each content key="@index" as |post|}}
    {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

In some cases, the order of the items in the `posts` array will need to change (via the `Ember.SortableMixin`), and these changes need to be reflected on screen. When I do this, however, it seems as though `content` isn't being binded correctly and doesn't update visually (though the order of the `posts` data is correct in the `PageController`).

I hope this makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of @locks in Freenode IRC, I have an answer. The issue had to do with the key that was being iterated on in the `{{#each}}` loop. By changing it to `key="@identity"` ([Ember 1.13.2](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11461)) it now works as desired.